# finding kurtosis for a dataset with boost

Tags: c++, boost

I have a vector of data and I want to find the kurtosis of the data set. I wanted to do so with Boost and here is what I have so far (not compilable):

```
#include <boost/math/distributions.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> a;
    a.push_back(-1);
    a.push_back(0);
    a.push_back(1);

    cout << "Kurtosis:"<< kurtosis(a) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't this work? My compiler gives me the error: "[...]\main.cpp|28|error: 'kurtosis' was not declared in this scope|"

Comment: If it wont compile, post the compiler error

Comment: The function is in another namespace, you need to use `boost::some::namespace::kurtosis(a)`. Replace `some::namespace` with the actual (which I don't know) namespace.

Comment: Disclaimer:I don't know enough about the problem domain to be absolutely sure of what I'm saying. My guess is that the algorithms in <boost/math/distributions.hpp> only work with [parameterized predefined distributions](http://www.boost.org/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists.html). An alternative using data sets could be [Boost.Accumulators](http://www.boost.org/libs/accumulators). [Here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2cDjQ9$0) is an example.

Comment: @llonesmitz I like your first example, I can work with that. Do you know how to reset an accumulator in Boost? Because I need to find the kurtosis for various datasets (in a loop...)

Comment: @llonesmiz I found this, describing how to reset the accumulator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195990/using-boostaccumulators-how-can-i-reset-a-rolling-window-size-does-it-keep-e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one you were not including the header for `kurtosis`:

```
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/kurtosis.hpp>
```

Even if you did, as you see it does not work with a straight `vector`, what you probably want to do is use an `accumulator_set` and more headers as well.

Here is a minimal example using `accumulator_set`, this shows a two methods to solve the problem:

```
#include <boost/math/distributions.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/mean.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/variance.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/kurtosis.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace boost::accumulators;

int main()
{
    accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::mean, tag::kurtosis > > acc;
    accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::mean, tag::kurtosis > > acc2;

    acc(2) ;
    acc(3) ;
    acc(4) ;

    std::cout << mean(acc) << " " << kurtosis(acc) << std::endl ;

    std::vector<double> v1 ;

    v1.push_back(2);
    v1.push_back(3);
    v1.push_back(4);

    acc2 = std::for_each( v1.begin(), v1.end(), acc2 ) ;

    std::cout << mean(acc2) << " " << kurtosis(acc2) << std::endl ;
}
```

Here is a link to the `Accumulators Framework` [User's Guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_accumulators_framework). This guide has some nice examples.

This previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316716/is-it-possible-to-use-boost-accumulators-with-vectors) found a way to use `vector`, although it is not straight forward at all and I could not get it work.