# boost::accumulator: which operators for sample_type?

Tags: c++, boost, vector, operator-overloading, boost-accumulators

I want to use a boost::accumulator for defining a moving average of my custom class:

```
boost::accumulators::accumulator_set<MySample, boost::accumulators::stats<boost::accumulators::tag::rolling_mean> >
```

My problem is that my sample is a user defined class (vector implementation of another library).

I've seen [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316716/is-it-possible-to-use-boost-accumulators-with-vectors) that's possible to define accumulators for std::vectors, but it does not specify which operator must be overloaded because it overloads them with `boost/accumulators/numeric/functional/vector.hpp`.

If I want to use accumulator with an user-defined sample class, which operator I must overload and how?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is going to differ depending on the stats you use, and sadly none of this is well documented. The best answer I can give is to try to compile it, look at the error message, add the needed operator, rinse, repeat until things work. :-/

Comment: Yes I'd like also to do this way, but when there are compilation errors with templates compiler messages can be very hard to read (for me) and I can't figure out easily what the problem can be. I'll try anyway.