# boost::accumulator: std::vector does not work with rolling_mean

Tags: c++, boost, vector, boost-accumulators

I'm following some thread ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316716/is-it-possible-to-use-boost-accumulators-with-vectors), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195990/using-boostaccumulators-how-can-i-reset-a-rolling-window-size-does-it-keep-e) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639953/boostaccumulator-which-operators-for-sample-type)) in order to calculate the rolling mean using std::vector as sample.

I've included headers of `numeric::functional` sublibrary in order to work with vectors

This code does not compile

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/accumulators/numeric/functional/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/rolling_mean.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::accumulators;

typedef accumulator_set<vector<float>, tag::rolling_mean> RollingMeanAccumulator;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<RollingMeanAccumulator> RollingMeanAccumulatorPtr;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    RollingMeanAccumulatorPtr ptr = RollingMeanAccumulatorPtr(new RollingMeanAccumulator(vector<float>(2), tag::rolling_window::window_size = 4));
    const vector<float> v = boost::assign::list_of(2.0)(3.0);
    (*ptr)(v);
    rolling_mean(*(ptr));

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles instead if I comment this line

```
rolling_mean(*(ptr));
```

So it seems that there's a problem in retrieving value. How can I fix this?

I'm using boost 1.48.

EDIT:

@doctorlove noticed in compilation error that `operator-=` misses for `std::Vector`. I've opened `boost/accumulators/numeric/functional/vector.hpp` and I've seen that definition of this operator misses. So I've added it in my code changing it in this way (sorry if it's not well written):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/accumulators/numeric/functional/vector.hpp>

namespace boost { namespace numeric { namespace operators {
template<typename Left>
    std::vector<Left> &
    operator -=(std::vector<Left> &left, std::vector<Left> const &right)
    {
        BOOST_ASSERT(left.size() == right.size());
        for(std::size_t i = 0, size = left.size(); i != size; ++i)
        {
            numeric::minus_assign(left[i], right[i]);
        }
        return left;
    }
}}}


#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/rolling_mean.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::accumulators;

typedef accumulator_set<vector<float>, tag::rolling_mean> RollingMeanAccumulator;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<RollingMeanAccumulator> RollingMeanAccumulatorPtr;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    RollingMeanAccumulatorPtr ptr = RollingMeanAccumulatorPtr(new RollingMeanAccumulator(vector<float>(2), tag::rolling_window::window_size = 4));
    const vector<float> v = boost::assign::list_of(2.0)(3.0);
    (*ptr)(v);
    rolling_mean(*(ptr));

    return 0;
}
```

I've taken the definition of `operator+=` in that header and adapted it.

I'm doing this way because in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316716/is-it-possible-to-use-boost-accumulators-with-vectors) the user says that vector operators must be defined before accumulator defines.

But even in this case I'm not able to compile it.

Comment: Not an answer, but if I specify `stat` in front of `tag@'rolling_mean' I get a clear error about `this->sum_ -= rolling_window_plus1(args).front();` i.e. it doesn't know how to do `-=` on a vector<T>

Comment: Thanks for the bug report. I've filed the bug at https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10452. Patches welcome if you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Ok thank you for the bug report. I've not reported before because I always think that when something does not work is my problem :)